# Вызов передаваемого метода в методе Java

Tags: java, сортировка

Нужно сделать сортитовку `JSONObject`. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Использую библиотеку `JSONSimple`. Хочу дописать свой метод `sort`. Но сделать это таки образом, что бы передавать туда нужный метод, который человек будет писать сам. Тоибшь, я написал конкретный метод сортировки. Я передаю его в метод sort моего объекта и мой метод вызывается в sort.

такое возможно?

Comment: вы хотите изменить существующий класс?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman расширить.

Comment: Я полагаю метод в метод передать нельзя, можно ссылку на объект передать, значение переменной, а метод в метод - никогда о таком не слышал, но я не могу всего знать

Comment: Можно передать анонимный класс, реализующий интерфейс с одним методом. Собственно, интерфейс `Comparator` для того и придуман.

Comment: Передать метод (лямбду) можно. Что значит расширить? Создать потомка с новым методом? Или изменить существующий?

Comment: @Tsyklop в яве нет методов-расширений. Расширить не получится. Пишите свой хендлер, или сервис. Других путей нет... Ну, есть ещё более сложный - обернуть классы JSON-а в свои классы обёртки, туда вставляйте что угодно. Ещё один из извращённых вариантов - скачать сорсы и сделать форк библиотеки, со своими блекджеком и сортировкой.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman >>Что значит расширить?<< есть такой сахар https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F которого в java не завезли... А то что вы описали называется "переопределение"

Comment: @test123 меня интересует, что имел ввиду вопрошающий

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте интерфейс компаратор:

```
public interface ICompare<T> {

    int compare(T obj1, T obj2);

}
```

Далее в своём методе сортировки его используете:

```
public void sort<T>(Collection<T> data, ICompare<T> compare) { ...
```

Аналогично решается лямбдами с 8 java.

Пример вызова:

```
sort(myCollection, new ICompare<MyClass>(){
    public int compare(MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2){
        return obj1.getName().compare(obj2.getName());
    }
});
```